# css3 transition - setting a property after transition has ended

Tags: css, css-transitions

I know how to to slide up and down a content box with css3 transitions and a specific height property and overflow set to 'hidden'.
But in my case I need this box to be overflow visible at the end of the slide-down-transition (it contains some absolute positioned elements that are larger than the box - to be specific a slide out menu).

Is there a way to delay the setting of the overflow-property?
I tried something like `transition: overflow 0s ease 0.5s;` but that obviously doesn't work.

best,

d.

Comment: Could you post the code of what you have currently?

Comment: I created a fiddle to show the "problem": http://jsfiddle.net/LWZqu/
Due to the overflow: hidden property the submenu on Item1 (hover over it) does get cut off.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you're using is absolutely right: `transition:property | time | easing | delay, another property`

Unfortunately, overflow isn't animatable at all ([See W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)). So it's not possible to use transitions on it.

I think the only solution would be using JavaScript and the transitionend-event:

**JavaScript**

```
["transitionend","webkitTransitionEnd","mozTransitionEnd"].forEach(function(transitionEnd) {
    document.querySelector("div").addEventListener(transitionEnd,function() {
        if(this.style.overflow == "visible") {
            this.style.overflow = "";
        } else {
            this.style.overflow = "visible";
        }
    });
});
```

**jQuery**

```
$("div").on("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd mozTransitionEnd",function() {
    $elem = $(this);
    if($elem.css("overflow") == "visible") {
       $elem.css("overflow","");
    } else {
       $elem.css("overflow","visible");
    }
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d6K9Z/)**

Comment: Thanks, but this way I also could use jQuerys slideUp / slideDown functions. I was hoping to get rid of this altogether.
Also, are these events really cross-browser-compatible?
Thanks anyway.